# error X = X.reshape(1, X.shape[0]) IndexError: tuple index out of range. How to fix that?

Tags: python, numpy

this is fragment of my code

```
def train(self, features, targets):
 for X, y in zip(features, targets):
            X = X.reshape(1, X.shape[0])
            outputs = self.feed_forward(X)
```

when I try to use the method with data:

```
train(np.array([gameDataList[n].ball_position, gameDataList[n].wall_position]),  np.array(gameDataList[n].upOrDown))
```

where gameDataList[n].upOrDown is an array e.g. [0.1, 0.9], and gameDataList[n].ball_position and gameDataList[n].wall_position are floats, I get this error.

Full code:

```
    #### Imports ####
import numpy as np


#### Neural Network Class ####
class MLP:
    ##### Constructor ####
    def __init__(self, n_input_nodes, hidden_nodes, n_output_nodes, lr):
        ## Network ##
        self.n_input_nodes = n_input_nodes
        self.n_output_nodes = n_output_nodes

        self.nodes = hidden_nodes
        self.nodes.insert(0, n_input_nodes)
        self.nodes.append(n_output_nodes)

        ## Weights and Biases##
        self.weights = []
        self.biases = []
        for i in range(1, len(self.nodes)):
            self.weights.append(np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, (self.nodes[i - 1], self.nodes[i])))
            self.biases.append(np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, (1, self.nodes[i])))

        ## Learning Rate ##
        self.lr = lr

        ## Activation Functions ##
        # Linear Activation
        self.linear = lambda x: x
        self.d_linear = lambda x: np.ones(x.shape)

        # Relu Activation
        def relu(x):
            x[x < 0] = 0
            return x

        def d_relu(out):
            out: x[x > 0] = 1
            return out

        self.relu = relu
        self.d_relu = d_relu

        # Sigmoid Activation
        self.sigmoid = lambda x: 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
        self.d_sigmoid = lambda out: out * (1 - out)  # assumes out is tanh(x)

        # Hyperbolic Tangent Activation
        self.tanh = lambda x: np.tanh(x)
        self.d_tanh = lambda out: 1 - out ** 2  # assumes out is tanh(x)

    def getWeights(self):
        return self.weights.copy()

    def getBiases(self):
        return self.biases.copy()

    def setWeights(self, weights):
        self.weights = weights.copy()

    def setBiases(self, biases):
        self.biases = biases.copy()

    #### Feed Forward ####
    def feed_forward(self, X):
        outputs = [X]

        logits = np.dot(X, self.weights[0]) + self.biases[0]

        for i in range(1, len(self.nodes) - 1):
            out = self.sigmoid(logits)
            outputs.append(out)
            logits = np.dot(out, self.weights[i]) + self.biases[i]

        out = self.sigmoid(logits)
        outputs.append(out)

        return outputs

    #### Backpropagation ####
    def backpropagation(self, X, y, outputs):
        weights_gradients = []
        biases_gradients = []

        d1 = y - outputs[-1]
        d2 = self.d_sigmoid(outputs[-1])
        error = d1 * d2

        grad = outputs[-2].T * error
        weights_gradients.append(grad)
        biases_gradients.append(error)

        for i in range(len(self.weights) - 2, 1, -1):
            d = self.d_sigmoid(outputs[i])
            error = np.dot(error, self.weights[i + 1].T) * d

            grad = outputs[i - 1].T * error
            weights_gradients.append(grad)
            biases_gradients.append(error)

        return weights_gradients, biases_gradients

    #### Training ####
    def train(self, features, targets):
        # Batch Size for weight update step
        batch_size = features.shape[0]

        # Delta Weights Variables
        delta_weights = [np.zeros(weight.shape) for weight in self.weights]
        delta_biases = [np.zeros(bias.shape) for bias in self.biases]

        # For every data point, forward pass, backpropogation, store weights change
        for X, y in zip(features, targets):
            # Forward pass
            X = X.reshape(1, X.shape[0])
            outputs = self.feed_forward(X)

            # Back propogation
            weights_gradients, biases_gradients = self.backpropagation(X, y, outputs)

            for i in range(len(weights_gradients)):
                delta_weights[-(i + 1)] += weights_gradients[i]
                delta_biases[-(i + 1)] += biases_gradients[i]

        for i in range(len(delta_weights)):
            self.weights[i] += (self.lr * delta_weights[i]) / batch_size
            self.biases[i] += (self.lr * delta_biases[i]) / batch_size

    #### Testing Methods ####
    def predict(self, X):
        # Gives prediction
        return self.feed_forward(X)[-1]

    def test(self, features, targets):
        predictions = self.predict(features)

        n_correct = 0
        for i in range(len(predictions)):
            prediction = np.argmax(predictions[i])
            correct = np.argmax(targets[i])

            if prediction == correct:
                n_correct += 1

        return n_correct / len(targets)

class GameData:
    def __init__(self, ball_position, wall_position, upOrDown):
        self.wall_position = wall_position
        self.ball_position = ball_position
        self.upOrDown = upOrDown
```

I collect data, and train my network, in this way:

```
gameDataList.append(GameData(ball.trt.ycor(), b.trt.ycor(),  [0.1, 0.9]))
mlp = MLP(2, [32, 32], 2, 0.0001)

n = random.randint(0, 999)

mlp.train(np.array([gameDataList[n].ball_position, gameDataList[n].wall_position]),  np.array(gameDataList[n].upOrDown))
```

Comment: This would be easier to help with a full code, or at least a short example. For now i would say try to print X before the problematic line, to help debug

Comment: printing X gives a float number e.g. 269.0

Comment: `np.array(269.0)` produces a 'scalar' array, an array with shape (), 0d. You can't do `X.shape[0]` on that.  Most likely it's the `np.array(gameDataList[n].upOrDown)` expression that's producing this 0d array.

Comment: When I print features, targets and X my sample output looks like this: features: [327.5 300. ], targets: [0.9 0.1], X: 327.5.

Comment: print(gameDataList[n].upOrDown) gives e.g. [0.9, 0.1]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was needed to write two square brackets instead of one.

wrong example:

```
np.array([gameDataList[n].ball_position, gameDataList[n].wall_position])
```

correct example:

```
 np.array([[gameDataList[n].ball_position, gameDataList[n].wall_position]])
```